# Using SDL with xCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, sdl

I know there are several questions regarding this. I have looked through them all but still haven't found an answer.

I'm trying to use SDL with xCode on my Mac. I'm using xCode 4.5

I followed [this](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php) tutorial exactly, twice! I even tried a second tutorial which was basically the same and it still didnt compile.

When i compile i get this error:

```
Ld /Users/shardy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_SetUp-efqnmqdzqqtkktbodsopeytuwjxt/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_SetUp normal x86_64
cd "/Users/shardy/Desktop/shardy/C++ Programs/GlutApps/SDL_SetUp"
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/shardy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_SetUp-efqnmqdzqqtkktbodsopeytuwjxt/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/shardy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_SetUp-efqnmqdzqqtkktbodsopeytuwjxt/Build/Products/Debug -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/shardy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_SetUp-efqnmqdzqqtkktbodsopeytuwjxt/Build/Intermediates/SDL_SetUp.build/Debug/SDL_SetUp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SDL_SetUp.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++ -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o /Users/shardy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_SetUp-efqnmqdzqqtkktbodsopeytuwjxt/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_SetUp

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_main", referenced from:
  start in crt1.10.6.o
 (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Followed by:

```
    "_main", referenced from:
 Start in crt1.10.6.o
 (maybe you meant:_SDL_main)
 Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I was originally using xCode 4.3 and it wouldnt compile, so i updated to xCode to 4.5 thinking maybe xCode was causing issues and tried everything again, but unfortunately, still did not compile...
I am not experienced enough to know how to fix this and i am out of relatable threads to read...
Thanks.

Comment: You said you looked through the other questions but didn't find an answer. You should update your question to say what you tried, but didn't work so other people don't give you answers that you've already tried. The error message is telling you the linker can't find a main() function. Assuming you have a main() function in your program, check its arguments. You may also need to add a search path to the SDL headers to the Header Search Paths build setting, which you can see in Step 6 of the LazyFoo tutorial you linked to.